# ¿Cómo llamar un parámetro y utilizarlo para acceder a un objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

tengo esta función donde tengo 2 parámetros, el parámetro "campo" lo utilizo para acceder a un objeto pero me lo toma como atributo del objeto y no hace referencia a mi parámetro.

```
async id(modelo, campo){
    const data = await modelo.all()
    console.log(data)
    
    var idmayor = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
        const id = data.rows[i].campo;
        if(id > idmayor){
            idmayor = id
        }
        console.log(idmayor)
    }
    idmayor + 1
    return idmayor
}
```

Aquí se puede mostrar mejor que no hace referencia a el parámetro "campo"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Intenta con `data.rows[i][campo]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es que le pides la propiedad campo. Las propiedades de los objetos tamibién pueden leerse como los elementos de arrays, cadenas y demás listas.
En este caso cambia el .campo por [campo]

```
        const id = data.rows[i][campo];
        if(id > idmayor){
```

Ahora estas accediendo a la porpiedad del objeto cuyo nombre está anotado en la variable campo.